# Magento 2- FREE SHIPPING for 3 or 3+ products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Magento2 experts. I need a help.

I need FREE SHIPPING on 3 or 3+ products. I set in cart price rule. 
in Action- "Quantity in cart  equals or greater than 3"

When I add same 3 products to the cart, it works. but, If I add separate 3 products in the cart, It doesn't work.

How can I solve it? Do I need an extension?

Comment: You don't need an extension. This can be done simply through admin. I have posted the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

@ magetips,
Your requirement can be simply done through the Magento admin. I have tested this in my local Magento-2.2.0 CE version.

To achieve this, go to the `Admin => Marketing => Cart Price Rules`

Enter the required fields for the Rule Information as follows,

```
Rule Name: Your desired rule name ,
Active: Yes 
Website: Main Website (In my case it's only Main Website) 
Customer Groups: (Choose the required customer groups) 
Coupon: No Coupon
```

Under the Conditions tab, set the condition as,

```
Total Items Quantity  is  3
```

Under the Actions tab,

```
Apply:  Fixed amount discount for whole cart
```

Leave all the fields empty and under the tab labelled "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)."

```
set Free Shipping: For matching items only
```

Please refer the attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Save the rule and clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up cart price rule as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to Magento, out-of-the-box the platform lets you only restrict shipping methods for specific countries. And that’s it.

To change shipping rates and costs, offer free shipping or use promotional rates, you need a third party shipping solution.

You can use this extension https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-shipping-suite.html   or  https://amasty.com/shipping-rules-for-magento-2.html

Comment: The stated requirement can be fulfilled using 'out of the box' functionality in M2 CE